# Directing to a landing page using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm currently using this in my .htaccess to remove the 'index.php' from my URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

But I also want to redirect the homepage (i.e. example.com) to a temporary landing page.  So example.com should be directed to the landing.html, but any pages for my application (i.e. those which run off index.php) need to be unaffected. I tried:

```
RewriteRule / landing.html [L,R=302]
```

and

```
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ landing.html [L,R=302]
```

But it messes up the CSS and relative paths for some reason.  Can anybody help?

The DocumentRoot in my httpd.conf is `/var/www/html/example.com/current` and this directory ('/current') is set to `AllowOverride All` whereas the /var/www/html/example.com is set to `AllowOverride None`

Comment: @UlrichPalha [please don't edit titles to add SOLVED](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-someone-elses-question); it adds noise, and there already exists a mechanism for a question being marked as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /landing.html
```

Comment: +1 for solving it yourself. Although be aware that `RedirectMatch` is a directive from `mod_alias` and not `mod_rewrite`. The `mod_rewrite` way of doing this: `RewriteRule ^(?:$|index\.php) /landing.html [R,L]`